# Laravel remove projectname/public/index.php from url

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, server, remote-access

All the url works perfect locally, On remote side things got messed up,

I have to access my routes like `example.com/project/public/index.php/someRoute`.

I removed the index.php from the url with the following `.htaccess` in **root** :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Next i have some hard coded urls in JS files , Basically i am using high charts, And by clicking on pie chart will show the concerned results. So the above `.htaccess` is not doing the job.

My current directory structure is `/var/www/html/project` where **server root** is `/var/www/html`.

How can i access my project with just `example.com`

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your server root if you want your application to be available on top level of your domain.

Comment: A quick method to adjust the server without placing bomb under it, Please.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: i mean i always misconfigure my apache

Comment: Basically just set the root of the vhost to `/var/www/html/project` and you should be good to go :)

Comment: Okay i changed it to `/var/www/html/project`, Now i have to remove the `index.php` only.